# Why aren't my basemap tiles showing up via ArcGIS Server

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online, cloudmade

I have a leaflet js script referencing the ArcGIS server imagery api.  The code worked fine up until about two days ago.  Now when I click on the layer there's a gray background.  I am using my local machine to deploy the map.  My cloudmade maptiles are appearing without error, and there in no error in the console regarding truncated images or anything of the sort for the ArcGIS imagery api.  I am using this api.
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9

[image]

[image]

```
var aLayerTwo = L.tileLayer('http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer',{

                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services">ESRI</a>, Created @ <a href="http://www.csun.edu/csbs/departments/geography/">CSUN Geography</a>',
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

This required the zoom format to be scripted with {z}/{x}/{y}.png.
I used this code snippet on my local machine and it worked, however I have the same map on another local machine, without the zoom format and it works as well, so there might be another server side issue with ArcGIS.  o